# Given a 1-form $\alpha$, when do distinct curves $C_{1,2}$ exist, such that $\int_{C_1} \alpha = \int_{C_2} \alpha$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha$ be a 1-form on a manifold $M$, with $d\alpha \neq 0$. Let $a$ and $b$ be two points in $M$. Is it always the case that we can find two curves $C_1 \neq C_2$ with endpoints $a$ and $b$, such that $$\int_{C_1} \alpha =\int_{C_2} \alpha \ ?$$
If not, are there conditions on the topology of $M$ that ensure it?

If the general case is too difficult, what about $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Take any path $D$ between $b$ and $c$ and consider $C_2=C_1\cup D\cup D'$ with $D'$ equal to the inverse of $D$

Comment: Do you know Stoke's theorem?

Comment: @Thomas ah, of course. But this feels like a trivial example. What if we require that $C_1$ and $C_2$ don't overlap?

Comment: @Robin What do you mean precisely ?

Comment: @Thomas Well, when I thought about this question I had in mind that $C_1$ and $C_2$ would be "significantly different" in some sense. A precise sense would be that the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is only $\{a, b\}$, or maybe measure 0.